# How to export your modules type when compiling Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a module written in typescript. Let's keep it simple:

```
// src/index.ts
import {AwesomeOptions} from './interfaces/Awesome';

export default class Awesome {
    constructor(options: AwesomeOptions) {
        // cool stuff
    }
}

// src/interfaces/Awesone.d.ts
export interface AwesomeOptions {
    // stuff
}
```

When I compile this to Javascript, I only get the `.js` files and no type definition is exported. So if I were to import this in another application that is also in Typescript, I wouldn't have my types.

I don't want to manually maintain a `index.d.ts` and have `"types": "./types/index.d.ts"` in my `package.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `declaration` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

> Generates corresponding `.d.ts` file

Comment: What if I want all of it compiled into one `index.d.ts`? Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think there is currently, but it's on the roadmap: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4433